# Error with uploading photo to facebook by Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, upload, photo

**I'm developing an app and it allow user to upload their photo to facebook with message.
But it not work smoothly, sometime it works perfect, and it return this error many times.**

```
2012-10-09 21:12:41.320 TimeLapse[1724:707] Error: HTTP status code: 200
2012-10-09 21:12:41.329 TimeLapse[1724:707] Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0xf352290 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0xf351840 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?sdk=ios&access_token=.....&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121003&message=Ghh&format=json, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?sdk=ios&access_token=....&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121003&message=Ghh&format=json, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0xf3518b0 "The request timed out."}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=200}
```

**Here is my code**

```
-(void)startPostPhotoToFacebook:(UIImage *)image withMessage:(NSString *)message {
    NSArray *arrPermission = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];

    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen) {
        NSLog(@"Session is opened already");
        [self postPhotoToFacebook:image withMessage:message];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Need to open session");

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:arrPermission defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                [self sessionStateChangedForPostPhotoToFacebook:session state:state error:error withImage:image andMessage:message];
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Open active session failed");
            }
        }];
    }
}

-(void)sessionStateChangedForPostPhotoToFacebook:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error withImage:(UIImage *)image andMessage:(NSString *)message {
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
            [self startPostPhotoToFacebook:image withMessage:message];
        }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
}

-(void)postPhotoToFacebook:(UIImage *)image withMessage:(NSString *)message {
    if (message == nil) {
        message = @"";
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];

    [params setObject:image forKey:@"source"];

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    FBRequestConnection *fbConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] initWithTimeout:10];
    [fbConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
            [myMainViewController finishPostPhotoToFacebook];
            [fbConnection release];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
            [myMainViewController errorPostPhotoToFacebook];
            [fbConnection release];
        }
    }];

    [fbConnection start];
}
```

Any one know how to fix this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You're seing timeouts from Facebook. See the description

```
NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.,
```

Your timeout setting is quite short. Facebook SDKs defaults timeout 180. 
Since you're dealing with image upload 10 second may not always be enough. Set it higher to something like 30 seconds.